# Pyinstaller windowed and noconsole is not working

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, pyinstaller

I'm using pyinstaller 3.3.1 and python 3.6.My problem is I cant run pyinstaller script in both no-console and windowed mode. My project is a web application built using Django 1.9.
Error Log:

```
    Error: [<class 'OSError'>, OSError(9, 'The handle is invalid', None, 6, None), <traceback object at 0x03B098A0>]
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 149, in get_response
  File "site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 147, in get_response
  File "crumbs_tableau\views.py", line 1603, in parser
  File "site-packages\django\shortcuts.py", line 67, in render
  File "site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 96, in render_to_string
  File "site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 43, in get_template
django.template.exceptions.TemplateDoesNotExist: helpers/error.html
Internal Server Error: /
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "crumbs_tableau\views.py", line 286, in parser
  File "crumbs_tableau\views.py", line 248, in mac_list
  File "subprocess.py", line 336, in check_output
  File "subprocess.py", line 403, in run
  File "subprocess.py", line 667, in __init__
  File "subprocess.py", line 905, in _get_handles
  File "subprocess.py", line 955, in _make_inheritable
OSError: [WinError 6] The handle is invalid
```

Answer (score 0):

Pyinstaller is not compatable with python 3.6 i was also getting the same issue and after some research i found that pyinstaller is only supported upto python 3.4 also your error logs is showing that

```
django.template.exceptions.TemplateDoesNotExist: helpers/error.html
```

that HTML file is missing which you have to add manually with **`"--add-data"`** param in pyinstaller